# "Esibizione" vs "esposizione/mostra"

Tags: word-meaning, word-choice

I have read the following sentence in an Italian learning tool:

> Abbiamo visto i tuoi disegni all'esibizione.

I thought that "esposizione/mostra" were the words used for a professional exhibition of art and "esibizione" was used for a generic display, such as a Science Fair or an exhibition of strenght. Can "esibizione" also be used for such an artistic event? If not, I assume it refers to amateur drawings (e.g., drawings of a child in the school).

Comment: Indeed, _esibizione_ does definitely not mean “exhibition” in the sense of public display of artworks and the like. It's an ugly claque from English. The closest meaning of _esibizione_ is some kind of sport, music etc. shows. Have I to repeat my opinion about those “learning tools”? :)

Comment: @DaG: Tuttavia, una delle accezioni di "esibizione" sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI05/GDLI_05_ocr_352.pdf) è «Esposizione, mostra; pinacoteca, museo», con questi esempi:

Comment: «*Rezzonico* [in Migliorini, 572]: A Londra, all’Esibizione, vidi  rappresentata  assai  bene  in  un  quadro  questa  celebre abbazia. *G. Raimondi*, 3-304:  Ci  eravamo  mossi,  per  visi­tare  l’eccezionale  esibizione  dell’arte  moderna.  Si  sa,  come sia  doveroso,  in  oggi,  la  costante,  aggiornata  informazione di cotesta instancabile arte, detta figurativa.»

Comment: Grazie della segnalazione, @Charo. Se mai questo uso è stato diffuso, adesso lo è quanto “cotesta”.

Comment: off-topic: I will never understand why Italian dictionaries like to take complex and/or archaic examples from books instead of making simpler examples, like the monolingual dictionaries of other languages do (eg Cambridge English dict, RAE Spanish dict, Larousse French dict, Duden German dict)

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: This could perhaps be an interesting question in itself. Of course one can't generalise: both in the past (Fanfani and Rigutini's _Vocabolario italiano della lingua parlata_) and today there _are_ dictionaries that put contemporary, spoken Italian first. On the other hand, one of the uses of dictionaries is to be able to read and study Italian literature, from before Dante to today, so they have to record those “complex and/or archaic examples” too.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista That would be an amazing question to ask on this site, and I encourage you to do so! One of the reason is because of a big debate going back at least to the 16th century and not completely over today about what the Italian language really is. One of the prevailing schools of thought was the so-called "purist" school (who composed the majority of the writers of the *Vocabolario della Crusca* for most of its existence), which argued for a language as close as possible to the Tuscan models of the fourteenth century, and so when writing the dictionary they took care that (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) every word could be traced back to that ideal model: hence the emphasis on literary models, and especially on archaic literary models. It even took decades for "recent" authors like Tasso to be allowed into the *Vocabolario*. Since most of the early dictionaries were modeled on the *Vocabolario della Crusca* (indeed it was the first dictionary ever written!), they kept up the tradition of explaining words via literary models, although they often opened up a bit the cast of "acceptable writers", allowing recent and sometimes even contemporary authors.

Comment: As an example of a very good, contemporary dictionary with a strong focus on modern Italian, check late [Tullio De Mauro's dictionary](https://dizionario.internazionale.it); see for instance the entry [_fatto_](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/fatto). Its main author was a great linguist especially interested in the different levels of use of Italian words and phrases.

Comment: De Mauro also edited the multi-volume _Grande dizionario italiano della lingua dell’uso_, which starting from its title gives a priority to Italian as it's used. See also De Mauro's [“vocabolario di base della lingua italiana”](https://www.internazionale.it/opinione/tullio-de-mauro/2016/12/23/il-nuovo-vocabolario-di-base-della-lingua-italiana), a list of most frequent Italian words, coded according to their use and register.

Comment: @DaG: Could you please write answer collecting the contents of your comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In contemporary Italian, [*esibizione*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/esibizione) does definitely not mean “exhibition” in the sense of public display of artworks and the like. It sounds like a claque from English like, say, *realizzare* (from “to realize”) to mean *rendersi conto*, or *sottomettere* (from “to submit”) to mean *sottoporre*, *presentare*. Nowadays, the closest meaning of *esibizione* refers to some kinds of sport, music etc. shows.

As pointed out by Charo, the *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* records some past occurrences of [*esibizione*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI05/GDLI_05_ocr_352.pdf) as “Esposizione, mostra; pinacoteca, museo” with the examples “*Rezzonico* [in Migliorini, 572]: A Londra, all’Esibizione, vidi rappresentata assai bene in un quadro questa celebre abbazia. *G. Raimondi*, 3-304: Ci eravamo mossi, per visi­tare l’eccezionale esibizione dell’arte moderna. Si sa, come sia doveroso, in oggi, la costante, aggiornata informazione di cotesta instancabile arte, detta figurativa”.

Comment: Thanks! Which word would an amateur exhibition of drawings done by children in a school use?

Comment: I'd say _mostra_, mostly.

Comment: off-topic: https://www.wordreference.com/iten/sottomettere says that one of the meanings of "sottomettere" is "to submit". http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sottomettere/ seems to agree: 2. Sottoporre, presentare al parere o al giudizio di altri: s. un quesito a un legale; s. una questione all’assemblea dei soci. In senso più astratto: s. un’idea, una tesi, una supposizione al giudizio della ragione, o al vaglio di una critica severa.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: I had especially in mind the calque used by some colleagues of mine, when they say that _sottomettono un articolo_ (submit a paper), which is especially funny used absolutely (not _sottomettere a qualcuno/qualcosa_), and in Italian sound simply like “subdue a paper”.